# How do I make the Values of JavaScript Equation Submit through a form?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a script that adds all items based on a form and then subtracts the smallest one of those items to create a new total. I want to be able to return the results in a form.

JavaScript:

```
var prices = [];

function remove(arr,itm){
    var indx = arr.indexOf(itm);
    if (indx !== -1){
        arr.splice(indx,1);
    }
}

function calculateSectedDues(checkbox, amount) {
    if (checkbox.checked === true) {
        prices.push(amount);
    } else {
        remove(prices, amount);
    }

    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = prices.length; i < len; i++)
        total += prices[i];

    var min = prices.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a-b})[0];
    if(typeof min === 'undefined') min = 0;

    var withDiscount = total - min;
    var discountAmount = withDiscount - total;

    //document.grad_enroll_form.total.value = total;
    document.querySelector("#value").innerHTML = "Total: $"+total+'<br>';
    document.querySelector("#value").innerHTML += "Discount: $"+discountAmount+'<br>';
    document.querySelector("#value").innerHTML += "New total: $"+withDiscount+'<br>';
}
```

HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="calculateSectedDues(this,5)" name="Scarf"> <span>Scarf</span><label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="calculateSectedDues(this,10)" name="Hat"> <span>Hat</span><label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="calculateSectedDues(this,20)" name="Jacket"> <span>Jacket</span><label><br>

<span id="value">Total: $0<br>Discount: $0<br>New total: $0</span>
```

You will notice that there are 3 different totals. All I want to submit through the form is the final total. The form is fully functioning and works great, I just want to include these results with the form.

& Here is a link to it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/danielrbuchanan/yjrTZ/5/

Comment: Where do you want to submit it to?

Comment: The server should really do the discounting since I could hijack the call and make it free.

Comment: @raam86 I just want to wrap "+withDiscount+" into <input type="text" size="8" name="total" readonly="readonly" style="border-bottom:none; border-left:none; border-right: none; border-top: none;" border="0"> so that it gets submitted with the rest of the form data

Comment: @epascarello It's being submitted with a bunch of other information that they entered and the "+withdiscount+" is just the results of javascript doing some math. It's not even close to being a store function or something anyone would even care to hack because there are no actual products being sold. Its more less just a survey.

Comment: Side-note:Querying the element 3 times as well as concatenating the string to `innerHTML` each time directly into the DOM is much more expensive than making the reference to the element only once. Look at the difference at only 100 iterations: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ABTgE/) i.e: Store references and build string in memory similar to this: `var newValue = ''; var x = document.querySelector("#value");` then `newValue = 'Total: $' +total+ '<br/>Discount: $' +discountAmount+ '<br/>New total: $' +withDiscount+ '<br/>';` then `x.innerHTML = newValue;`

Comment: Can't find the form in your fiddle.. but what you'd want to do is ad a hidden input-field `<input type="hidden" name="finalTotal">`and set its value to your calculated final total (in your `calculateSectedDues` function for example). On the serverside you'd fetch that value again. Done.

Comment: @GitaarLAB so I would define withdiscount = finaltotal in the js and then call a <input type="hidden" name="finalTotal"> somewhere in the html?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment (and question):

In your form, add a field `<input type="hidden" name="finalTotal">`
Then have your function `calculateSectedDues` end with: `document.getElementById('finalTotal').value=withDiscount;`

Together it could look like (a little re-factored, look at what I did with 'value'):

```
function calculateSectedDues(checkbox, amount) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        prices.push(amount);
    } else {
        remove(prices, amount);
    }

    var total = 0, i = 0, len = prices.length;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        total += prices[i];
    }

    var min = prices.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a-b})[0];
    if(typeof min === 'undefined') min = 0;

    var withDiscount = total - min;
    var discountAmount = withDiscount - total;

    //document.grad_enroll_form.total.value = total;
    document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "Total: $"+total+'<br>'
                                               + "Discount: $"+discountAmount+'<br>'
                                               + "New total: $"+withDiscount+'<br>';
    //set hidden input value
    document.getElementById('finalTotal').value = withDiscount; 
}
```

Once you submit this form, the post-data the server receives will contain a value called 'finalTotal' containing the value of 'withDiscount'.

Just never do (especially TRUST) this in real life when money is involved; anyone can post whatever they want!!

Comment: Can I change the input type to test it so I can visually see that it is pulling the finaltotal?

Comment: yep, no problem, or add a button: `<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('finalTotal').value)">check hidden value</button>`